# Deleting Files and Paths Together otherwise Rollback in PHP

Tags: php

In my script i'm deleting file paths in database firstly. If deleting paths is done. I'm deleting files.

I realized that something wrong in my ftp panel. Some files are orphan. There is no path in database but i have files.

You know that we can use try catch block for commit and roll back database queries. Is there any technique for files. For example we'll delete paths and we started to delete files. If there exists a problem during deleting files. We have to rollback Files and Paths.

Comment: show the code please.

Comment: code is not important. We're talking about technique. If there is a technique i can do it. I'm asking commit and rollback possible.

Comment: Are you using version control?

Comment: If it is in unix based system or windows or some other operating system because different os have different filesystem and garbage process.

Comment: And if you show code it may helpful to answer because are you using php function or if use shell execution like `\`rm -f filename\`` in php

Comment: @CihanKüsmez Did you find a way to do what you are asking about?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a back-up policy stating, all files must be backed up before deletion and once successful, you can decide what to do with the back-up files.

Another solution would be to move all deleted files into a temporary "Delete" folder and once all files have been successfully removed, delete the "Delete" folder, this way you can recall the files

Comment: The backing up process involves moving files together to another folder and that has the same problem as deleting files together .. still want to rollback if some file failed! .. how to do that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need something like "deletion queue" - the daemon that is running in separate process and waiting for commands.

When you decide to remove data, you add paths in queue-table first, if paths added successfully, you delete records, else roll back transaction. This guarantees that all patch appears in deletion journal.

The daemon listens for table with paths and remove files, let say, one-by-one. There is an algorithm (it isn't single correct algorithm, you may select different logic):

1. Start transaction
2. Remove single path from table
3. Remove file
4. Commit transaction

If step #3 fails you can re-try operation little later (maybe network connectivity problems), or report to the admin about failure (file is readonly or doesn't exists).

Answer (score 0):

I thing that it is possible to do this using external tools or filesystems

- special filesystem with rollback feature can be used - zfs, btrfs, ...
- version control system can be used to rollback to previously committed state

Doing this from PHP may need some extra work - locks, calling executables available only for root, etc.